# compare Shape object serialized out as xml with PP Shape object

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I have object `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape` and I need to know if it is related (the same as) to object `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape`.

Maybe I can compare ID's? But to me looks like OpenXml.Presentation.Shape has a different id than PowerPoint.Shape.

Answer (score 0):

I printed name and ID for two random shapes:

```
Oval 3
 4 
=========
Cross 4
 5 
=========
```

slide1.xml contained this:

> ```
>       <p:sp>
>           <p:nvSpPr>
>               <p:cNvPr id="4" name="Ovaal 3"/>
>               <p:cNvSpPr/>
>               <p:nvPr/>
>           </p:nvSpPr>
>           ...
>       </p:sp>
> ```

and

> ```
>       <p:sp>
>           <p:nvSpPr>
>               <p:cNvPr id="5" name="Kruis 4"/>
>               <p:cNvSpPr/>
>               <p:nvPr/>
>           </p:nvSpPr>
>           ...
>       </p:sp>
> ```

The only difference seems to be that the name is translated between Dutch and English, but the ID remains the same.